# How do I listen for webpack (watchpack) changes in --watch mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, onchange, watch, webpack

I'm currently experimenting with webpack and would like to call a function everytime webpack/watchpack detects changes when in `--watch` mode. The [watchpack API](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/blob/master/README.md#api) describes a `.on('change')` method, but how can I hook up with the already running instance of watchpack?

Executing like this:

```
webpack --watch --colors --progress
```

And here is my *webpack.config.js*:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        style: './styles/master.less',
        homepage: './styles/homepage.less',
        messaging: './styles/messaging.less',
        places: './styles/places.less',
        profile: './styles/profile.less',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '_tmp/[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('raw!less')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('_tmp/[name].css')
    ]
};
```

I've also tried creating a preLoader, but since loaders are intended for processing source code, it's probably not a good way to go.